# Adding ressource to ressources in fbs (python)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, fbs

I am trying to make a desktop application with qt. I now want to turn it into a real app. Therefore I am using the fbs module.

I have a main python file and sone resources. I want to access my resources from the python file.

I know that I can get one of the resources with the function `app.get_resource('my_resource')`. This is no problem. But now I also want to add resources from the python file. How can I do that? Is there a similar function to `app.get_resource`?

I have done it with entering the file path: `"src/main/resources/base/my_resource"` into the code until now. But that only works when the code is not in the application because there the file structure is different.

Comment: the objective of the resource folder is for static data, that is, it should not be changed or modified in runtime. Why do you want to add data in a folder where all resources must be read?

Comment: I want to download some images from the internet and then display them into the application. Furthermore I want to copy a file into that folder.